# Как передать картинку во Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Eсть ссылка в шаблоне Flask вида:

```
<img src="/api/get_img?name=logo_img" alt="">
```

Роутер **/api/get_img** вставляет туда картинку.
Свои картинки успешно встают (которые находятся по пути **path_to_img**):

```
with open(path_to_img, mode="rb") as f:
    img = f.read()
res = make_response(img)
res.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
return res
```

А вот со стороннего адреса, например из адреса: https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/33/multfilm_lyagushka_32117.jpg
не встают.
Пробовал даже так:

```
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen

links = 'https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/33/multfilm_lyagushka_32117.jpg'
image = Image.open(urlopen(links))
res = make_response(image)
res.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpg'
return res
```

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался:

```
url = 'https://avatarko.ru/img/kartinka/33/multfilm_lyagushka_32117.jpg'
import urllib.request
img = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
res = make_response(img)
res.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
return res
```